# Improving the Bookmarklet Experience - Though Hacking?

Tags: javascript, xss, bookmarklet

So I have a site specific bookmarklet that create a page with a toolbar (using localstorage to set/get variables) and then creates an iframe for a destination site, say `www.example.com`. [Idea heavily borrowed from the wonderful RWD Bookmarklet (http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/) ]. It works great, but I wanted to provide that a clickable link to that bookmarklet (because it is a pain to add a bookmarklet in an Ipad) but unfortunately that results in the obvious XSS cross-site problems since the link does not reside within `www.example.com`.

To improve this experience I was wondering if it would be possible to do have a popup (like twitter's) which would exploit an existing generic `loadScript` function currently present on `www.example.com`.  From within the javascript console on `www.example.com` I currently can invoke a `supervar.loadScript("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/blah/thefile.js")` and it works. Which means I do not need to append or cross load the js into the iframe but I would need the iframe itself to invoke the `supervar.loadScript` call.

It is *possible* to invoke the supervar.loadScript on say a window.onload/document.ready type scenario or would the context of the popup code be pointing to about:blank/notexample.com in which case the `supervar` would not exist.  Could `window.postMessage` be of any use?

### UPDATE: Clarification

I am trying to have a button which would contain javascript code that in turn would open a new window/tab to a site but would be able to invoke a command on a variable that will be present when the DOM is ready.
Again, I'm quite new to XSS so I'm not sure if this is a security problem on the site.  I'm not trying to access variables from one site to the next, just a means to load a userscript on a site without having to use a bookmarklet.

For a real test:

Visit: `firsttaste.kraftcanada.com`.
Open the javascript console and then enter:  `nitroWidget.loadScript("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/fcfbpfdmzrxywh9/mwolfe_alert.js")`
This will execute the mwolfe_alert.js which merely contains an alert message.

Is there a way that I could create a clickable link on a site outside of *.kraftcanada.com which would create a popup/new tab that upon the {document,window,$}.onload/read would invoke the nitroWidget.loadScript?

Comment: Fighting XSS issues is going to be trouble all the way. If you get it working in one browser, it probably won't work in others.

Comment: I understand a lot about bookmarklets (you'll see I answer almost exclusively related questions) and I've done some tricky stuff with them, but I can't make heads or tails of your question. If you are trying to have users click a link on one domain that opens a page on a different domain which is outside of your direct control, and then run JS on that other domain, you will fail. And if you succeed, then you have found a critical cross-site attack vector that will probably get closed quickly once your users report it.

Comment: @DG.I've added further clarification, I'm not sure if it is a cross-site attack vector or if it is possible to leverage the existing loadScript call on a popup.